# How to get date format in php

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I am doing an unit test about this method

```
function stripTime($datetime) {
    return new \DateTime($datetime->format('Y-m-d'));
}
```

and I want test that the output(date) returned has the correct format `Y-m-d`

for example :

```
$actual = $this->stripTime(new \DateTime);
$this->assertEqual('Y-m-d', $actual->getFormat());
```

I know `getFormat` method doesn't exist, but i need something like.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: why do you pass a DateTime and then create another DateTime of it? This doesn't make sense. Since a DateTime doesn't have a format. It just is able to return a string in the specified format.

Comment: or in other words: what do you think getFormat() could return?

Comment: @Jeff the function creates a new DateTime object using only the date portion (i.e. not the time) of the passed-in object.  It *strips* the *time*, as the function name suggests.

Comment: ah, ok. So it basicly sets hours, minutes and seconds to default. Note, that the Object $actual still will have those params. Only set to current time.

Comment: I want que getFormat returns a string 'Y-m-d'

Comment: @jjoselon  DateTime objects don't have a "format", which is why your question is confusing.  Do you really want to check that the value conforms to some format (which is nonsensical) or that the value has no time part (more correctly, it is midnight)?

Comment: That's not possible, because all the params are there. But (not that I know) no format is saved to that DateTime-Object. You could of course extend that Class...

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns a `DateTime` object, so that test makes no sense. You'd be better off using `assertInstanceOf` to check that it's a DateTime object and that it has the time set to the default instead of what the original `DateTime` object had.

Depending on your system settings, that default value may be the server time at the moment of creating the object, 00:00:00 in the current timezone (system default or set by `date_default_timezone_set()`), or 00:00:00 in GMT.

If you want to have full control over that, specify it in your function:

```
function stripTime($datetime) {
    return new \DateTime($datetime->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'), new \DateTimeZone('GMT'));
}
```

Comment: yes, I also think about test with `assertInstanceOf`, But I want more control about that format is set inside `stripTime` method...

Comment: There is no format. A `DateTime` object does not store any format. It stores day, month, year, hour, minute, second, microsecond, timezone, etc. in internal variables. Only when you call `$datetime->format('Y-m-d');` are those internal variables rendered in the format you requested. That format is not stored internally because it is only used for rendering the values at that one moment.